# Is it possible to change google sheet gid?

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a new google sheet with multiple sheets. Usually a first sheet has `gid` equal to `0`. So after playing around with my sheets I think I've lost that first sheet, probably it was deleted many iterations ago.

I wonder is here anyway to create a new sheet with `gid 0` or change any current sheets `gid` to `0`?

Comment: It seems to be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65680717/904846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sheet IDs are immutable, so there is no way to change an existing sheet's `gid`. You could create a new spreadsheet and copy all the sheets from your current spreadsheet there, resulting in a spreadsheet with a first sheet that is blank and has a `gid` of `0`.

To copy tabs one at a time from one spreadsheet file to another, click the dart ▼ in the tab bar at the bottom of the browser window and choose **Copy to > Existing spreadsheet**.

To copy multiple tabs while keeping formulas that use cross-sheet range references working, follow the instructions in [Is there a way I can merge spreadsheets together without losing references?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/25896767?msgid=25901483)